# Java blackjack swing gui ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing

I've just started Java a week ago and have finished my first blackjack program.
I want to enhance it by using Java swing (ImageIcon) so that each time I draw a card, let's say an ace it actually displays the ace as an image on the screen or my current hand.
I have written this program which displays the cards I want:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TenCards extends JFrame {

    public TenCards() {

        ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[10];
        // Saved the card images as 1,2,3...10.gif in my package
        // looped them into the images list
        for (int i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new ImageIcon((getClass().getResource(i + ".gif")));

            // testing by displaying 7,8 and 9 cards
        }
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(1, 1, 1));
        add(new JLabel(images[7]));
        add(new JLabel(images[8]));
        add(new JLabel(images[9]));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame = new TenCards();
        frame.setTitle("Testing!");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

> **Now my question is, given I have my blackjack class or program in another file, how do I combine both classes so that I can use all this image stuff in my blackjack program?** I tried copy pasting my TenCards program into the Blackjack one to no avail :( If anyone could lend me a hand or point me towards the next step I would really appreciate it.

---

**EDIT** I have now included my blackjack program and deleted the other because stackoverflow wouldn't accept both combined because there was too much code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class myblackjack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> player = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> dealer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Ace is 1 as per Amos' instructions
    for ( int i =1; i <= 10; i++){
        cards.add(i);}
    // The 3 face cards representing 10
    for (int z = 0; z <= 2; z++){
        cards.add(10);}


    player.add(cards.get((int) (Math.random()*12)));
    player.add(cards.get((int) (Math.random()*12)));
    dealer.add(cards.get((int) (Math.random()*12)));
    dealer.add(cards.get((int) (Math.random()*12)));
    System.out.println("Your cards: "+player);
    boolean moreplayer = true, morecomputer = true;
    System.out.println("Hit 0 to stop, 1 for another card");
    int s1 = sc.nextInt();
    while (moreplayer || morecomputer){
        int dealersum = 0, playersum = 0 ;

        for (int p = 0; p<dealer.size(); p++){
            dealersum = dealersum + dealer.get(p);
        } if (dealersum<15){
            morecomputer = true;
            dealer.add(cards.get((int) (Math.random()*12)));
                dealersum = dealersum + dealer.get(2);
            }else{ morecomputer = false;

        }if (s1 == 1){

            moreplayer = true;
            player.add(cards.get((int) (Math.random()*12)));
            for (int b = 0; b<player.size(); b++){
                playersum = playersum + player.get(b);


            } System.out.println("Your cards: "+player);
            System.out.println("Hit 0 to stop, 1 for another card");
            s1 = sc.nextInt();
            }else if (s1 == 0){ 
                moreplayer = false;
                for (int b = 0; b<player.size(); b++){
                    playersum = playersum + player.get(b);


                }}if (playersum>21 && (moreplayer || morecomputer)){
                moreplayer = false; morecomputer = false;
                System.out.println(dealer + "dealer");
                System.out.println("You've gone bust player, computer wins!");

            }if (dealersum>21 && (moreplayer || morecomputer)){
                moreplayer = false; morecomputer = false;
                System.out.println(dealer + "dealer");
                System.out.println(player + "player");
                System.out.println("Computer has gone bust, player wins!");

            }if (playersum>dealersum && (!morecomputer && !moreplayer) && (dealersum<=21 && playersum <=21)){
                System.out.println("Player wins!");
                System.out.println(dealer + "dealer");


                moreplayer = false; morecomputer = false;
            }if (dealersum>playersum && (!morecomputer && !moreplayer) && (dealersum<=21   && playersum <=21)){
                System.out.println("Dealer wins");
                System.out.println(dealer + "dealer");

                moreplayer = false; morecomputer = false;
            } if ((dealersum == playersum) && (!morecomputer && !moreplayer) && (dealersum<=21 && playersum <=21)){
                System.out.println("TIE!");
                System.out.println(dealer + "dealer");

                moreplayer = false; morecomputer = false;


        }
            sc.close()  ;

    }

    }
    }/** I didn't consider suits, ace is value 1 and all 3 face cards are worth 10 points */
```

regards,
M

Comment: As long as your class tencards is in the same package as your logic class and other assorted class you should easily be able to combine them.  Most likely since I would assume at most you have only a couple of classes you probably only have a defualt package....that being said you should just need to instantiate your image when your new card is drawn.

Comment: What would the instantiate command for the image consist of?

Comment: There's simply not enough information to ascertain any really possible answers.  You may need to re-model your code, taking ideas from both and producing a new solution...

Comment: for example in card class I assume you have a draw function draw() returns a ace then Tencards card = new Tencards("ace");  so pass the ace to the constructor and now you match up the actual image with whatever identifier you use to match your ace   so think about it like createing a new image object for each card....maybe I'm not sure what the most efficient way to do it is

Comment: @MadProgrammer very true I am just spit balling right now.....it would be helpful to see some actual code other than just an example of how spacesick created images

Comment: I have now edited the post to show my blackjack program, I'm still unsure how to combine both classes -

Comment: @BigT 
I tried to add the command
add(new JLabel(images[7])) to my blackjack program but it didn't recognize it (both my classes are under the same package)

Answer (score 2):

> "how do I combine both classes so that I can use all this image stuff in my blackjack program?"

It's not really a good idea to try and combine a GUI program with a console program (your first piece of code being a GUI program, and the latter a console program).

To better learn GUI programming with Swing, see [**Creating a GUI with Swing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). A few of the main sections I'd focus on are

1. [**Using Swing Components**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) where you can find all the different components  available to you.
2. [**Writing Event Listeners**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) as Swing (all GUI frameworks for that matter) are event driven, meaning one event, such as a button to draw a card being pressed, causes a label with a card image to be added to player hand
3. [**Laying out Components within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) where you will learn how to use different layout managers to give your interface a clean structured look with all your components.

What you are asking is a very broad question.. and the only really way it can be answered is if someone takes the time to study your entire program and spend time on thinking about how to refactor the entire program. Most of us don't have the luxury of that time, or to be blunt, just don't care enough to put in that effort. Converting a console program into a GUI program is not an easy task.

So I suggest you take the time to learn Swing, by going through the tutorials linked. *Then* if you have a specific question, like *"Why doesn't my button draw a card?"*, we can surely assist you, given you provide the necessary code, effort shown, and detailed description and understanding of the problem.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is...don't...

You're shifting between paradigms.  What I mean is, you're original program is using the command line/procedural driven paradigm things happen in a well defined order), where as you're attempting to move to a GUI/event driven paradigm.

In a event driven environment, things can happen in any number of order and you need to be prepared to handle it.

One of the most significant paradigm shifts you will face is separating your model/virtual view of the game from the physical/UI view of the game.

This is an important concept as it will not only make your program easier to write, but also to change.

This is best described in [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and Swing implements this concept (loosely)

Take the time to read through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), design your model (of the game) and understand what things you will need to tell the view and what things the controller can change about the game.