# Is there a simple way to make a Java application that combines the command line and Swing graphics?

Tags: java, swing, command-line-interface

I'd like to know if it's possible to take a Java command-line application, like a game of Hangman, and
add some graphics to it, yet maintain the command-line interface. This will be used in a high
school context so it doesn't need to be industrial-proof code.

Based on similar ideas from earlier assignments in the class, I started with a rough outline like
this. This might be missing a need to override `repaint()` (I'm not sure).

```
public class Hangman extends JFrame {

    static int state1;
    static int state2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        // ...

        // This is a main loop for a console application.
        while (true) {
            // prompt for input
            System.out.print("...");
            int value = scanner.nextInt();

            // process value. print data as needed.
            //
            // break if completed.
            //
            // static variable like state1 and state2 may be modified
            //
            // ...

        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // paint an update of every change in state of the console app 
        // general example here:
        g.drawLine(0, 0, Hangman.state1, Hangman.state2);

    }
}
```

So my question is whether a framework like this can be made to work as a combo command-line and graphics application, or whether a completely different approach is needed.

Comment: My instinct would be to add a `TextField` into the UI, and have the user enter data into there.

Comment: For the love of all, don't do it, don't try to shove a linear command-line program together with an event-driven gui library as it leads to madness

Comment: also, always best to [search for similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+combine+gui+and+command+line+site:stackoverflow.com) first

Comment: Also, have a look at [MadProgrammer's answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718776/522444), a clear and concise message that agrees with my answer. Also look at [Paul's similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718497/522444)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be as categorical as Hovercraft... I've developed quite a few apps where they started off as CLI caterpillars and blossomed/bloomed into GUI butterflies in due course.  But I've only ever done it in the context of proper test-driven development... and the pupa stage (neither caterpillar nor butterfly) is a big step.  Certainly it is not trivial.  The fact that you don't seem to be aware that Swing was basically replaced by JavaFX many years ago tends to suggest that you may possibly not yet understand the issues involved.

Comment: @mikerodent: re `"I'm not sure I'd be as categorical as Hovercraft..."` -- if the OP is going to mix linear console and event-driven GUI, then they will need to well understand threading and GUI-specific concurrency issues, increasing app complexity and risk needlessly. Better (as in safer, cleaner *and* easier) to choose one or the other and stick with it.

Comment: @mikerodent: re `"...The fact that you don't seem to be aware that Swing was basically replaced by JavaFX many years ago tends to suggest that you may possibly not yet understand the issues involved."`. Based on OP statements like this: `"This will be used in a high school context .... Based on similar ideas from earlier assignments in the class, I started with a rough outline like this. ...."`, I'm betting that this is for a school assignment where the Swing GUI library was taught, and so I will bet that the OP has little choice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I concur.